# Rearranging tabs in Chromium is broken (possibly due to upgrade to impish)

Tags: chromium, wayland

Previously I was able to rearrange my tabs in Chromium. When dragging them down, they would emerge as a seperate window.

Today, my tabs immediately emerge as a separate window, and can only be reinserted into the original window at the last position by using a contextual-menu on the tab (Move tab to another window).

I wonder how I can solve this: Is it a bug?

Chrome does *not* suffer the same problem currently.
Could it be related to Wayland being in the mix (I was still using X before the upgrade to impish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [seems to be a bug in Chromium 97](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1279532). According to the bug report, it has been fixed in beta versions of Chromium / Chrome 98. Your installation of Google Chrome probably is still on version 96, or already on the 98 beta.

Comment: My chrome is on 97.0.4692.99-1 , a little higher than chromium (via snap): 97.0.4692.71. But thanks, I will await for the bug to be resolved, or try the beta.

Thanks!

Comment: And now wait for my reputation to grow to 15 before I can upvote your answer. How does this work :)

Comment: @KaiS You get reputation basically by doing things that other people on this site consider good and helpful: https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation